# How can i read an array of arrays in shell script?

Tags: shell, multidimensional-array

I need to build an array of arrays to store some directories in different clouds.
How can a build it and them in a shell script?

> drivers=( goo_drive=( $HOME/path1 ) meg_drive=( $HOME/path2
> $HOME/path3 ) one_drive=( $HOME/path4 ) )

Answer (score 0):

```sh
all=()
arrays=( "${goo_drive[@]}" "${meg_drive[@]}" "${one_drive[@]}" )
for array in "${arrays[@]}"; do
    all+="$array"
done
```